# Passing an array elements to bob.js formatString function

Tags: javascript

I want to pass array elements to bob bob.string.formatString format string so that I can pass any number of arguments and it will automatically fill in the required parameters in the placeholders. Here is what I have tried.

```
var string = "Hi {0} and {1}."; 
var x = "Hello";
var y = "world";
var result = test(string ,[x,y] )

function test(string ,args){
//return bob.string.formatString(string, args[0] , args[1]);  -> This gives me correct output
str = bob.string.formatString.apply(string , args);
console.log("final string:" + str); // --> This gives me only Hello
```

I want "Hi Hello and world" as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `apply` is the `thisArg`. It provides the value of `this` for that function call. Instead of:

```
str = bob.string.formatString.apply(string , args);
```

you should call it with:

```
str = bob.string.formatString.apply(null, [string].concat(args));
// or
str = bob.string.formatString.apply(bob.string, [string].concat(args));
```

You could also define your function as:

```
function test(string) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    str = bob.string.formatString.apply(null, [string].concat(args));
    console.log("final string:" + str);
}
```

This also takes 1 to N arguments and passes them to `formatString`. In ES6 you could use the official rest parameter:

```
function test(string, ...args) {
    str = bob.string.formatString(string, ...args);
    console.log("final string:" + str);
}
```

Comment: I got this error "Cannot format string: argument at index 1 not found." I called my test function in the same way `var result = test(string ,[x,y] )` and added your test function implementation.(tried both functions)

Comment: Ah, call the test function I gave as `test(string, x, y)`. Added those just to show how to do a general argument forwarding function. If you need to use arrays for passing args to format, keep your original test function.

Comment: You saved my life! Thanks a lot :)